# WPF MVVM storing user controls in the ViewModel? A big no-no?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to host a user control inside my main window but I'm having a hard time deciding how to implement it into my view model.

First, I created a separate view model for the user control and used a data template to map it to the control before hosting it inside a `ContentControl`:

**Data template:**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:TaskbarIconViewModel}">
    <tb:TaskbarIcon/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**XAML:**

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding TaskbarIconViewModel}"/>
```

If I were to use this setup, how would I call methods on the user control and how would I set the properties of the user control, either in XAML or the view model?

Secondly, I had the idea to hold the user control in the view model and then bind it to a `ContentControl` once again. this seems wrong to me and against MVVM. Is this right? Is it acceptable to hold controls inside of a view model?

**In the view model:**

```
public TaskbarIcon TaskbarIcon { get; set; }
```

**XAML:**

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding TaskbarIcon}"/>
```

What's the best course of action here?

Comment: Displaying an icon is a view concern, in general. Is there some reason you want it available in the view model?

Comment: It's a custom control that allows me to interact with a task bar tray icon. This specific example requires that I can show a baloon from the  tray icon by calling a method on the control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing UserControl(s) in the ViewModel: a big no-no? **YES** 
The ViewModel shouldn't be aware of the view.

What you're talking about is what [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)'s regions do, don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to hit PluralSight and work through their Prism courses :)